# Hosting a Silverlight application in a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, silverlight-4.0, wizard

I need to write a little wizard application into which a user inputs some information. I was going to write this as a silverlight application.

The website hosting it is developed using ASP.NET MVC 2 (.NET 4.0). Is it possible to host a silverlight application in an ASP.NET MVC 2 View?

Also, are there any good frameworks out there for creating online wizard applications like the one I need to create?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to host a silverlight application in an ASP.NET MVC 2 View?

Yes, simply use the VS2010 Silverlight 4.0 application creation wizard and select ASP.NET MVC site to host it instead of classic ASP.NET site:

[image]

> Also, are there any good frameworks out there for creating online wizard applications like the one I need to create?

Hard to say from *I need to write a little wizard application into which a user inputs some information*