# whats the best way to include silverlight pages into an asp.net-mvc site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

i have an asp.net-mvc website and i want to merge in some functionality from a silverlight app.  i could rewrite but for the time being i wanted to see if there is any clean way to "include" a few silverlight pages inside my mvc app.

what is the recommended way of doing this ?

Comment: almost duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302584/hosting-a-silverlight-application-in-a-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The New Silverlight Application Wizard allows you to choose ASP.NET MVC as host application and it will setup the necessary parts:

[image]

All that you need is to embed the Silverlight application in any view:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SomeSlApp.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
</object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
```

You could also write a [HTML helper](http://silverlighthack.com/post/2010/11/16/Creating-a-ASPNET-MVC-HTML-Helper-for-Silverlight.aspx) allowing you to achieve this in a cleaner way.

Comment: i don't want to create a new site so i dont think the wizard is going to help but i will look into your HTML Helper suggestions.  How would you organize the code in a visual studio solution.  keep the silverlight code in a seperate project ??

Comment: @ooo, oh yeah definitely keep the Silverlight code in a separate project. Otherwise you will be targeting the full CLR which won't work under Silverlight.